# Select2. How can i get the first value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

The html is rendered via

```
<select class="select2" id="foo">
    @foreach (var m in Model)
        <option value="@m.Id">@m.Value</option>
</select>
```

I read - write the selected option on a cookie.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cookie = getCookie("foo");
        if (cookie != null) 
            $('#foo').val(cookie);
         else 
            $('#foo').val("GET_FIRST_VALUE");

        $('#foo').trigger('change');

        $(function () {
            $('.select2').select2({
            }).on("change", function (e) {
                setCookie("foo", $("#foo").val(), 365);
            });;
        });
    });
</script>
```

On the very first time the app initializes, where cookie is not set, 
how can i get the first value of my `Select2` component?

Answer (score 1):

You can update `$('#foo').val("GET_FIRST_VALUE");` to be like below.

```
$('#foo').val($("#foo option:first").val())
```

Selector `$("#foo option:first")` will select first `option` inside `#foo`.

Comment: You can accept the answer as it solved your problem.